# How would I write the getter and setter methods for my class?

Tags: java, methods, compiler-errors, computer-science

I'm a beginner with java and I need to write the get() and set() methods for my PlayingCard class and I need someone to explain why I keep getting an error saying "actual and formal argument lists differ in length".

This is the code that I was given to work with:

```
 class PlayingCard
 {
      int value;
      String suit;
 }
```

and I have to write these methods:

- getValue
- getSuit
- setValue
- setSuit

This is the last rendition of the code that I tried, but I don't know why I keep getting the error.

```
 public int getValue() {
     return value;
 }
 
 public String getSuit() {
     return suit;
 }
 
 public int setValue() {
     return value;
 }
 
 public String setSuit() {
     return suit;
 }
```

I tried to follow the lecture slides that we were given, but nothing seems to be working. As I said before, I'm a newbie at working with java, so I don't have the eyes to understand what is wrong just yet.

Comment: By the way, if the main purpose of your class is to transparently communicate immutable data, make the class a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395): `record PlayingCard ( int value ,  String suit ) {}`  The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `hashCode` & `equals`, and `toString`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### `void`

I'm pretty new programmer too so bear with me, I don't think your setter methods should return anything. Usually they're void and look something like:

```java
public void setSuit(String assignedSuit){
    suit = assignedSuit;
}
```

This code means whenever you call upon your setSuit method with the a string parameter assignedSuit it can change the suit variable of your card object.

I think your getter methods are fine though. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried doing what you said, and it ended up fixing my problems with my code.

Answer (score 2):

set() methods should not have a return. void type should be used.

```
class PlayingCard
{
    int value;
    String suit;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }
   
    public void setSuit(String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Getter and setter methods in Java are used to control how other classes access and modify an object's data. They involve making class fields private and providing public methods to retrieve (get) and update (set) these fields. If you don't care about having private variable then there is no reason to have getter and setter. Then you can just access the variables by writer: `PlayingCard.value`

```
class PlayingCard {

private int value;
private String suit;

public PlayingCard(int value, String suit) {
    this.value = value;
    this.suit = suit;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public String getSuit() {
    return suit;
}

public void setSuit(String suit) {
    this.suit = suit;
}
```

}

Comment: If I were to remove my private variables, what would playingCard.value do? Does this do the same as this.value?

Answer (score -1):

An alternative to that will be

Adding these:

```
@Getter
@Setter
```

before starting your "public class"

For example

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class PlayingCard
 {
      private int value;
      private String suit;
 }
```

then you will not required to add in get set method one by one

By importing the lombok

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
```

P.S. can try to add in "private" before initializing your variable